# Jump to documentation buffer with company-mode

Tags: company-mode, documentation

I have recently switched from `auto-complete-mode` to `company-mode` and I having fun. Recently I had to write some Emacs Lisp code. I start typing my function, completion candidates are shown, I press `F1` and the documentation opens up in another buffer. I would like to *jump to the documentation buffer*, but, as I type `C-x o` it gets closed. Any hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a way built in to company-mode to do this, but you can add your own key binding to `company-active-map`.

As a quick experiment I took the `company-show-doc-buffer` implementation and simply removed the `company--electric-do` wrapper:

```
(defun my/company-show-doc-buffer ()
  "Temporarily show the documentation buffer for the selection."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((selected (nth company-selection company-candidates))
         (doc-buffer (or (company-call-backend 'doc-buffer selected)
                         (error "No documentation available"))))
    (with-current-buffer doc-buffer
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (display-buffer doc-buffer t)))
```

You could bind this to another key, for example C-F1, to "permanently" open the doc buffer:

```
    (define-key company-active-map (kbd "C-<f1>") #'my/company-show-doc-buffer)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: [here](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/238#issuecomment-63917865) is the issue I opened on the GitHub project's repository, and they suggested to go down this path.

Comment: I just wanted to post my little tweak in case you want this window also get selected

(defun my-company-show-doc-buffer ()
  "Temporarily show the documentation buffer for the selection."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((selected (nth company-selection company-candidates))
         (doc-buffer (or (company-call-backend 'doc-buffer selected)
                         (error "No documentation available"))))
    (with-current-buffer doc-buffer
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (select-window (display-buffer doc-buffer t))))

Answer (score 4):

Author's comment on a page [comparing company-mode to auto-complete](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/68):

> > What happens when you press F1 in company mode
>
> It uses pop-to-window to display the help buffer, but hides it before the next command (unless that command is scroll-other-window or scroll-other-window-down).

Based on that, you can only scroll the documentation buffer, not jump to it.

But, looking at the [code](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/blob/master/company.el) for `company-show-doc-buffer`, I noticed that it uses `company--electric-do`, which will call interactively any commands in `company--electric-commands`. Normally, it contains only `scroll-other-window` and `scroll-other-window-down`, but maybe you can add `other-window` to that list.

Comment: I just tested like this:

`(defvar company--electric-commands '(scroll-other-window scroll-other-window-down other-window) "List of Commands that won't break out of electric commands.")` but it doesn't work. As I type `C-...` the help buffer closes. The same putting `(add-to-list 'company--electric-commands 'other-window)` in my init file.

Comment: Yeah, looks like company--electric-do uses `save-window-excursion` to save/restore the the window configuration, so it won't work. You might be better off binding your own 'show doc' command to a key in the `company-active-map`.